# Do both series play at the same time?

Tags: night-watch-cycle

Lukyanenko wrote the *Night Watch* Cycle and a spin--off (*School Watch*).

Do these stories play in different timelines and interaction between those characters is impossible?

Comment: Well if they play at the same time, the fuaran stuff would be nice too, I'd open another question linking this one if the answer didn't address this xD

Comment: @DVK removed one question. as soon as i get an answer, and the spinoff is before or at the same time as the main story, i will ask the other one...

Comment: Huh, somehow didn't heard of these spin-offs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "School" cycle - specifically, the events of "School Watch" - start **"one year after"** the events of book 3 ("Twilight Watch"), when Anton was dealing with Konstantin Saushkin and Fuaran on Baikonur Spaceport and after  Anton's daughter, the Great Sourceress, was born:

> *{{ During the book exposition, shown as protagonists's thoughts, the book is discussing the history of the School in "School Watch". English translation mine, "shoot-from-the-hip" quality.}}*
>
> В девяностые пансионат обветшал и захирел. Парк выродился в дремучий лес. Какие-то ушлые дельцы решили было выкупить землю и построить коттеджный поселок. Но вмешались Дозоры.
>
> In the nineties the boarding school became dilapidated and decayed. The park degenerated into a dense forest. Some savvy hustlers had decided to buy land and build a cottage village. But Watches intervened.

...

> Было это на самом рубеже тысячелетий. Времена смутные даже для Иных. В Москве едва не рванула воронка инферно размерами побольше той, что висела над Хиросимой в сорок пятом. Следом какая-то непонятная история произошла в Санкт-Петербурге. Говорят, разбирались Темные друг с другом. **Наконец, совсем недавно, год назад, был инцидент с Иными на Байконуре**. Что именно там случилось, толком никто не знал. Информацию Дозоры не распространяли, тем более что это как-то затрагивало Инквизицию. А ее всегда и все затрагивало... И Великая Волшебница снова родилась, и не где-нибудь, а в Москве.
>
> It happened at the turn of the millennium. The times of troubles, even for the Others. In Moscow, an inferno crater magnitudes bigger than the one that hung over Hiroshima in nineteen forty-five, almost blew up. Following that, some incomprehensible story took place in St. Petersburg. They said Dark Others had internal fight {{*DVK - that's likely a reference to events of "Лик Чёрной Пальмиры"/"The face of Dark Palmira"*}}. **Finally, more recently, a year ago, there was an incident with the Others on Baikonur**. No one really knew what transpired. Patrols did not disseminate any information, especially since it somehow affected the Inquisition. And it was always affected by everything ... And the Great Sorceress was born again, and not just anywhere, but in Moscow.

**Additionally, we can place School Watch at 2004 or 2005 absolute time:**

> Голубева Анна Сергеевна. Дата рождения: 15 сентября 1990 года. Итого четырнадцать полных лет....
>
> Golubeva, Anna Sergeevna. Date of Birth: September 15, 1990. Thus, fourteen years of age.

She turned 14 in September 2004, so the school year covered in the book was 2004-2005 school year.

Comment: To address your original concern - this means that at the very least, the START of "School Watch" predates the events of "Sixth's Watch" by a couple of years, at the end of which Anton stopped being the Other (ironically, that got totally spoiled for me since I wasn't even aware Sixthth Watch was published :)

Comment: I'm totally sorry, having spoilered you. But you can't say it wasn't marked as such xP And thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Armin - no need to be sorry. I'm one of those people who really aren't all that hung up on spoilering what they consume. I am quite pleased to see Night Watch questions being posted :)

Comment: well, for me that depends on how much I like that series. I couldn't stand spoilers in things like the night watch series, but with other things like breaking bad i was totally fine ^^

Comment: @Armin - I tend to re-read things I like many times, so for me, the greatest pleasure of any work is most assuredly NOT in unexpected twists and surprises :)

Comment: But reading, or in my case hearing it the first time , not knowing what to expect, screaming in your head what the person should do, that is a pleasure you only have once.

Comment: @Armin - yep, I guess that's why most normal people don't like spoilers :)