# Can they give that person the power back?

Tags: night-watch-cycle, sergei-lukyanenko

In the sixth book of the Night-Watch-Cycle

> Anton loses all his powers.

Also, in the spinoff School Watch a djinn appears, which can draw things into existence. this spinoff plays before the sixth book as answered here:

[Do both series play at the same time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/114621/29135)

> In the story of the spinoff, the djinn creates a new fuaran. Also, after some other stuff happened, the djinn extracts its essence into a bottle, which is given to the inquisition.

Since this essence could be used to create a new fuaran, I was wondering if the person from the main story could regain all powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just (finally) got around to reading *The Sixth Watch* and this was my question as well. At the end of the book, Anton says that he has been made completely human, his magical temperature increased so that he can no longer absorb power in the way Others can, but the Fuaran has proven to be capable of transforming a human into an Other by reducing their 'temperature'. The original was confirmed to have been destroyed when Kostya took it into space as the Watches, and presumably the Inquisition also, tracked both him and it until they burnt up.

In *The Last Watch* however, it's said that Arina was able to create an imperfect copy that was able to raise Gennady Saushkin's level to that of a Higher vampire. Knowing this, it seems perfectly plausible that she could recreate the initial spell that turns humans into Others in the first place. Even if Anton could only be raised to the 7th level, he could still regain a lot of what he'd lost- namely the effective immortality.

I think the only debatable issue with this is whether the Twilight would allow it to happen; Anton's powers were lost as a sacrifice to the Two-in-One, so it's possible that the Twilight would force him to honour that sacrifice by preventing his magical temperature from being lowered again. Alternatively, and perhaps more likely, it's possible that even if it were possible the Watches and Arina wouldn't want to risk provoking the Two-in-One into rematerializing by cheating their way out of the sacrifice.

Comment: This is a good analysis.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes... in theory

As you mentioned, Fuaran is a book that can turn a human into Other, by lowering their "magical temperature".

Now, if I remember right at least one copy of Fuaran still exists (one used by Kostya), then the witch Arina reconstructed it again to increase the power of Kostya's father. Since she has never been captured (and she has a VERY good memory), she could probably re-write the book again. Also, Nadya has almost unlimited power and only lacks experience.